# Unable to play the audio in different device when HDMI is connected

Tags: nvidia, hdmi

I have connected the second monitor with the HDMI but the audio plays on that device only. I have connected Bluetooth headphones, but on switching from Settings -> Audio, it is still playing on that monitor.

When I remove the HDMI cable, it switches to laptop integrated speaker, then I go back to settings and change to Headphone, and it works.

As soon as I plug the HDMI back, it forcefully redirects the audio output to the external monitor and the same issue happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was some misconfig in the pulseaudio. So removing the local config directory `rm -rf ~/.config/pulse` and logout-login solved the problem.